# Skeletal animation with ASSIMP

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I have been trying to implement skeletal animation in my own 3D openGL/c++ game engine using ASSIMP to import the models.

I think that the problem is caused by the calculation of the bone matrices, loaded as uniform variables in the shader because if I assign them to identities, the mesh is loaded in its bind pose.

These are the functions I use to initialize and calculate the ready bone matrices:

```
    void Joint::AddToSceneGraph(GameObject* root)
    {
        GameObject* parent = root->FindChild(m_name);
        //m_globalInverseMatrix = inverse(root->GetTransform().GetMatrix());
        parent->AddComponent(this);
        while (parent->GetParent() != root)
            parent = parent->GetParent();

        parent->GetTransform().SetParent(NULL); (1)
    }

    mat4 Joint::GetMatrix()
    {
        mat4 ans = /*m_globalInverseMatrix*/GetTransform().GetMatrix()*m_offsetMatrix;
        return ans;
    }
```

Since I am trying to render the model in its bind pose I wont supply you the code of calculating animation matrices.

Some clarifications - I have a Transform class which has Transform* parent and whose GetMatrix() method calculates the matrix from the parent's one, scaling and translating vec3s and rotation quaternion so the relation between parent and child is taken in consideration. I assume that the parent's transform of the root joint has to be NULL thus its matrix - identity, which is the purpose of (1). Although I am not sure for this assumption, I am sure that the node with the root of the skeleton and the node, containing the meshes, are siblings.

Also I am not sure weather I should use `m_globalInverseMatrix` and furthermore what exactly is its purpose.

In general I think the main issue I have is misunderstanding of how ASSIMP calculates the `offset matrix` or so called `inverse bind pose matrix` and how to invert its effect. This issue results in the model looking "packed" in itself :

[image: this is maybe the most famous md5 model]

Answer (score 4):

From the docs in Assimp, the offset matrix of the bones transforms from the mesh space to the bone space.

I managed to render the bind pos with a hierarchy similar to yours (if I have not misunderstood, you have a root node with two children, one spawning the skeleton hierarchy and the other spawning the mesh). What you have to do is set the `m_globalInverseMatrix` to the inverse transform of the node containing the mesh. Then, each bone's transform is:

`boneTransform = m_globalInverseMatrix * boneHierarchyTransforms * boneOffsetMatrix`

where the `boneHierarchyTransform` comes from traversing the tree up to each bone node and the `boneOffsetMatrix` is the one you mention and I referred to in the first paragraph.